# Verifying denormalized index with normalized index in elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, multithreading, elasticsearch, indexing, opensearch

I have denormalised data stored in Elasticsearch 7.9 from normalised indexes.
Consider separate indexes A,B,C,D having their own independent data.

Now consider a new index E which is formed by combining data from A,B,C,D. Assume A1,B1,C1 and D1 are documents from the respective indexes.

Now E1 is something like:

```
E1:{ A1:{}, B1:{}, C1:{}, D1:{}}
```

I want to disjoin E1 back into A1',B1' and so on and compare if

```
A1' = A1,B1' = B1,C1' = C1,D1' = D1
```

I could have used GET api to get each of these individually but for a scale of millions of records the entire process becomes too long. Is there a way to internally run this within ES via some script?